# Install a package from tarball using puppet

Tags: activemq-classic, puppet

I'm trying to install ActiveMQ using puppet. this package comes in tar ball. how can I make sure each and every file is being pushed (recursively) from puppet and it makes sure the service is running. As it has its own executable in 'bin' dir.

Comment: Read the documentation for the `file`, `exec`, and `service` resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask is it essential to install activemq from a Tarball? It'd probably be easier to manage as a package, such as a yum or apt install.

Managing tarballs is always going to be more difficult, especially when updating versions, or dealing with issues like downloads failing.

I would recommend using an existing activemq module from the forge:

https://forge.puppet.com/modules?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&sort=latest_release&q=activemq

To give you a general idea of how it might look, here's some basic code that could work:

```
  $activemq_home = "/usr/local/activemq"

  package{"java-1.6.0-openjdk":
    ensure => installed;
  }

  $activemq_version = "5.4.3"

  user {"activemq":
    ensure => present,
    home => $activemq_home,
    managehome => false,
    shell => "/bin/sh",
  }

  group {"activemq":
    ensure => present,
    require => User["activemq"],
  }

  Exec{path => ["/usr/local/bin","/usr/bin","/bin"]}

  $puppet_cache = "/usr/local/src/gitorious"

  file {$puppet_cache:
    ensure => directory,
    owner => "root",
    group => "root",
  }

  exec { 'download_amq_src': 
    unless  => '/usr/bin/test -e ${activemq_home}/apache-activemq-${amq_version}-bin.tar.gz',
    command => 'cd /tmp && /usr/bin/wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/apache-activemq/${amq_version}/apache-activemq-${amq_version}-bin.tar.gz',     
    require => File[$activemq_home], 
}

# Unpack the archive in the amq user directory
exec { 'unpack_amq_src':
    onlyif  => '/usr/bin/test -d ${activemq_home}/apache-activemq-${amq_version}-bin',
    command => 'cd $amq_home && /bin/tar -xf /tmp/apache-activemq-${amq_version}-bin.tar.gz',
    require => Exec['download_amq'],
}

  file {"/etc/init.d/activemq":
    ensure => file,
    mode => 755,
    owner => "root",
    group => "root",
    content => template("activemq/etc/init.d/activemq.erb"),
    require => File["/etc/activemq.conf"],
  }

  service{"activemq":
    enable => true,
    ensure => running,
    require => File["/etc/init.d/activemq"],
  }

  file { "activemq.xml":
    path => "$activemq_home/conf/activemq.xml",
    ensure => present,
    mode => 644,
    owner => "activemq",
    group => "activemq",
    content => template("activemq/activemq.xml.erb"),
    require => File["/etc/init.d/activemq"],
    notify => Service["activemq"],
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really helpful. :)